# What's the meaning of "drag" in this context?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

This is a comment from a forum discussion:

> This is OT.  You must cook every meal to perfect macros. You then must buy tupperware and drag it into work the next day. That is all you are allowed to eat for lunch. If you do not bring leftovers you must only eat at a local restaurant.

What does the poster mean by *drag it into work*? Is he using *drag* figuratively, or *drag something into something* is a phrasal verb for something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, the phrase “drag it into work” *means* the same as “take it into work”, but the first phrase has overtones the other doesn't.  It implies it is a chore or is onerous or bothersome to take the leftovers, in their tupperware casket, to work.